# finite simple groups (non abelian ) can be genarated by two elements.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

With reference to  [Peter Clark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements/59300#59300)
answer here, 
I have the following question

He says most finite simple groups can be generated by two elements $G=<x,y>$ where $x$ has order 2 and $y$ has order 3.

I want to study this result,If somebody know the reference Kindly mention it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have edited your other question!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Sir, Should I do it now

Comment: Why not just make this a comment on Peter Clark's answer?

Comment: @MikePierce Sir , I don't have enough reputation. It reads "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: @MikePierce (by this he means "50 reputation on MathOverflow".) Still, it's always possible to edit your own posts regardless of reputation, go ahead.

Comment: The language of "most" sounds like he's not actually alluding to a particular result.